# OpenCV: Why SIFT and SURF detectors crashes?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc4.9

Why do the SIFT and SURF detectors crash?

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
  Mat image = imread("TestImage.jpg");

  // Create smart pointer for SIFT feature detector.
  Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
  vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

  // Detect the keypoints
  featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints); // here crash
  // ...
}
```

The error is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I use OpenCV 2.4.8, gcc 4.9 and Ubuntu. If I use the other types of features it runs normally. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you *sure* that `image` is valid ?

Comment: Does it need to be on gray scale?

Comment: I don't know - check the docs - what I was referring to though was the fact that there was no error checking to see whether `image` had been loaded successfully.

Comment: SIFT/SURF are extracted on grayscale images, althought I'm not sure you need to pass a grayscale image explicitely. But this would have crashed with an exception, not core dumped

Comment: i have tested it, grayscale still gives me that crush

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried to call [`initModule_nonfree()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf-operator)?

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  initModule_nonfree();
  Mat image = imread("TestImage.jpg");

  // Create smart pointer for SIFT feature detector.
  Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
  vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

  // Detect the keypoints
  featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints); // here crash
  // ...
}
```

Also, you didnt check the pointer featureDetector which is probably null (since you have not called initModule).

Comment: It seems that `initModule_nonfree()` was the problem... I did not knew about it

Comment: fixed my link to the documentation in the answer.

Comment: "If you are using the C version", How do I know that? I used just C++

Comment: There is another explanation about calling initModule in [`Algorithm::create`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=algorithm#algorithm-create), I doubt the problem is really about using C/C++