# OpenCV: How to know that I use C version or not

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have met a problem of Sift and SURF feature detectors. I have fixed it by calling `initModule_nonfree()` ([see the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23630704/1360570)). On [their site](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf-operator), they say that I shall use it if I am "using the C version".

I have not use any `IplImage`. So, **How do I know that I use C version and not C++?**

Comment: if you're using cv::Mat, and functions from the cv:: namespace - that's the c++ api (recommended). the  initModule_nonfree() issue applies to both apis, so keep it.

Comment: That's it, I am using cv::Mat, so C++, and they were saying that initModule_nonfree() shall be called in C version. But anyway, I'll know from now that I shall use it

Comment: note, that in c++ , apart from the FeatureDetector::create("SIFT"); way, there's a SIFT and a SURF class, that you can create directly. and you don't have to call initModule_nonfree() in that case. yea, admittedly, confusing!

Comment: The documentation that I quoted about that matter in your previous question is wrong. The initModule does apply to C and C++. Check the doc on the Algorithm::create function